# Fluent change of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I make an image gallery. I have 9 fields, in each field there is an image (or better, there is a part of image). In total, I have 9 big images and in each of that fields there is a 1/9 of each big image.

When I "hover" one of these nine fields, I need to change the other fields to the rest of this image and see the whole image over all fields.

Okay, this I am able to make with CSS and a little bit of JS, but I am looking for any javascript/jQuery effect, let´s say to change image by image from right top corner to left bottom corner, any fluently change between images.

Example, with 3 images:

#### HTML:

```
<img onmouseover="show_image('r');" rel="1" src="" class="r">
<img onmouseover="show_image('r');" rel="1" src="" class="r">
<img onmouseover="show_image('b');" rel="2" src="" class="b">
<img onmouseover="show_image('g');" rel="3" src="" class="g">
<img onmouseover="show_image('b');" rel="2" src="" class="b">
<img onmouseover="show_image('g');" rel="3" src="" class="g">
<img onmouseover="show_image('r');" rel="1" src="" class="r">
<img onmouseover="show_image('b');" rel="2" src="" class="b">
<img onmouseover="show_image('g');" rel="3" src="" class="g">
```

#### CSS:

```
img {float: left; width: 30%; height: 100px; margin: 0 9px 9px 0;}
img:nth-child(3n+3) {margin-right: 0;}

.g {background: #070;}
.b {background: #00f;}
.r {background: #f00;}
```

#### JavaScript:

```
function show_image(id) {
$('img').removeClass().addClass(id).removeAttr('onmouseover');
}
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zG7JN/))

Do you have any idea how to make the fluent change of images when hover one of them?
In HTML there should be all 27 small images, it´s no problem, I´m looking for the switching effect. You can send links for examples, maybe I only don´t know how to call what I need :-)

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a jsFiddle you **must** also include your code here

Comment: You can link fiddles here without problem, but you should post some Code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand your question now!

You mean, when you hover over on an image, the rest of images get replaced by its remaining parts and whole of the 9 images match up to complete the image?

You need to set these functions!

Try to remove the `onmouseover` function from the element, and try to use jQuery for that!

Lets start the example!

The example image tag:

```
<img src="some/source/to_file.png" alt="photo" class="image5" id="red" />
```

First you need to get the image on which the mouse over event occured, like this:

```
$('img').mouseover(function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var class = $(this).attr('class');
  if(id == 'red') {
    if(class == 'image5') {
    /* replace all the other images with red one 
     * here you will check the image's class too, which is the number
     * location where it is present at!
     */
    }
  }
}
```

After this, you will need to shift the image's back too! For that, use this:

```
$('img').mouseleave(function () {
  // shift the src tag back as
  $('.image5').attr('src', 'its/src/to_file5.png');
  $('.image7').attr('src', 'its/src/to_file7.png');
  $('.image6').attr('src', 'its/src/to_file6.png');
}
```

And so on.

And yes, you will be needed to keep the images in the browser as downloaded files on the page load and just keep shifting them once the user hover's over!

In your fiddle, all you're doing is adding a classname but you are not removing or reverting it back on `mouseleave` event; there is no `mouseleave` event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don´t need to return to default scheme. There is no problem. I wrote more in comment to Shadow Wizard´s solution, look.

Comment: Then you can use animate, and change the first one and then for the second and then for the final! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery UI [`switchClass()` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/) which allows you to animate whole class.

Here is a working code sample using your as basis:

```
function show_image(id) {
    $('img').each(function() {
        var className = this.className;
        if (className == id)
            className = '';
        $(this).removeClass().switchClass(className, id, 1000, 'linear').removeAttr('onmouseover');
    });
}
```

Since it's removing one class and add other, if the one you remove and add is the same it won't work hence the need to check and reset.

As for "linear" it's just my personal choice of easing method, choose your own from [the full list](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/).

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zG7JN/2/).

Comment: Ahh sorry, thanks for the updated fiddle link!
To your solution. I need to change the thumbs one by one. You can imagine it like a sheet of paper (those 9 thumbnails is one sheet of paper and when hover st. you pick the sheet up in the top right corner and turn that to left bottom corner). Not change all thumbs in one moment.